# no preview for ContentVersion when inserting from Apex

Tags: apex, contentversion, preview

I'm using the following code to generate ContentVersion.

```
    String title = 'sample file.txt';
    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf(jsonBodyPretty),
            Title = title,
            ContentLocation = 'S',
            PathOnClient = title
    );

    insert contentVersion;
```

But when I try to preview it from Salesforce 'No Preview is Available'.
If I download file and re-upload - everything is ok.

Have someone was able to create Previews from Apex for ContentVersion?

Comment: I have the same issue. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you need the contentDocumentID for the preview, after insert the contentVersion get the ContentDocumentId

`Id cdID = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: contentVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId;`

I hope this help you.

Comment: And what do I need to do with Content Document in order to enable preview?

Comment: You can use lightning:openFiles https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:openFiles/example

Comment: I wrote that the problem with Preview text generation and not with Previewing file itself. I can preview it from standard view.

Comment: I am having the same issue, when file was uploaded using apex no preview, but same file using file upload, give preview, how to find the issue?